# Linq to xml - XDocument - How to read nested nodes

Tags: nested, linq-to-xml

I have below xml, my objective is that for given ProductName (for eample Spot) and given language for example ("en-gb")  i want all translations. So in this case (ProductName=Spot and language="en-gb") the output should be TRADE STATUS, TRADE ID, VALUE DATE

I tried below linq query but it prints all the translations for "ProductType=Spot" instead of all translations for ProductType=Spot and language="en-gb"

```
    var qry = doc.Descendants("Product")
    .Where(p => p.Attribute("ProductName").Value == "Spot")
    .Where(p =>   
   p.Element("Fields")
 .Element("Field")
.Element("Translations")
.Element("Translation")
.Attribute("language")
.Value == "en-gb")
.Select(p => new { Text = p.Value });
```

It would be great if someone can suggest linq query for above objective.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Products>
  <Product ProductName="Spot">
    <Fields>
      <Field FieldName="tradeStatus">
        <Translations>
          <Translation language="en-gb">TRADE STATUS</Translation>
          <Translation language="fr-fr">fr_TRADE STATUS</Translation>
          <Translation language="cz-cz">cz_TRADE STATUS</Translation>
        </Translations>
      </Field>
      <Field FieldName="tradeId">
        <Translations>
          <Translation language="en-gb">TRADE ID</Translation>
          <Translation language="fr-fr">fr_TRADEid</Translation>
          <Translation language="cz-cz">cz_TRADEid</Translation>
        </Translations>
      </Field>    
      <Field FieldName="valueDate">
        <Translations>
          <Translation language="en-gb">VALUE DATE</Translation>
          <Translation language="fr-fr">fr_ValueDate</Translation>
          <Translation language="cz-cz">cz_ValueDt</Translation>
        </Translations>
      </Field>    
    </Fields>
  </Product>
  <Product ProductName="Forward">
    <Fields>
      <Field FieldName="dealtRate">
        <Translations>
          <Translation language="en-gb">DEALT RATE</Translation>
          <Translation language="fr-fr">fr_dealtrt</Translation>
          <Translation language="cz-cz">cz_dr</Translation>
        </Translations>
      </Field>
      <Field FieldName="dealtAmount">
        <Translations>
          <Translation language="en-gb">DEALT AMOUNT</Translation>
          <Translation language="fr-fr">fr_dAmtt</Translation>
          <Translation language="cz-cz">cz_dealtAmtt</Translation>
        </Translations>
      </Field>      
    </Fields>
  </Product>

</Products>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question, below linq query works

```
var qry = doc.Descendants("Product")
    .Where(p=>p.Attribute("ProductName").Value=="Spot").Descendants("Fields").Descendants("Translations").Descendants("Translation")
    .Where(t => t.Attribute("language").Value == "en-gb")
    .Select(t => new { Text = t.Value });
```